# Control the progress bar using Jobs

Tags: java, eclipse-rcp, jobs

I am trying to update the progress bar in my GUI using the IProgressMonitor, which is passed to the run method of job. 
But i am not able to do the same.
Has anyone tried that.

Also i read job.setUser(true); method displays the progress, can anyone help me with the code for the same

Comment: Sorry but I don't understand what you are asking. What is 'your GUI'? Is this progress in a view? A Job you are creating? A wizard? ..... what?

Comment: @greg-449 i have main thread which initializes the UI(SWT based).Now addition to this i declared a job to control the background functioning. I want to display the completion level of this functionality on a progress bar present in the UI.

Comment: If your app is just SWT you can't use Jobs or IProgressMonitor because that is Eclipse plugins only.

Comment: @greg-449 No, it is a plugin project. But the UI design is in SWT

Comment: A Job will only display progress in a pop-up dialog, the Eclipse status line and the Progress View. Possibly you want `ProgressMonitorPart` or `ProgressMonitorDialog`. Wizards already have a ProgressMonitorPart.

Answer (score 1):

I was also requiring a similar type of feature in which if any job runs in the application then I want to show the progress of that job.

So in my Eclipse 4 application, I added the trim bar and tool control inside it. In which I added the progress bar in it UI.

By adding the below code done the trick

```
Job.getJobManager().setProgressProvider(new ProgressProvider() {
        @Override
        public IProgressMonitor createMonitor(Job job) {
            return monitor.addJob(job);
        }
    });
```

Comment: Could you share details how you integrated this code snipped? Where does the monitor comes from?